# GRUB freezes when USB is connected

Tags: grub2, usb

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my new HP Spectre x360 and GRUB freezes completely if I have an USB connected.

I only have one USB port so I cannot try more ports as the rest are USB type C. It happens with my Logitech USB mouse receiver as well as my wired usb keyboard. So far it does not happen if I connect my laptop fan base.

Is this a known issue?

I have read this could be fixed setting the legacy booting or something like that in the BIOS but I do not see such an option in mine.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware? Do not change to legacy boot.[Guide] Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Spectre x360 13" 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422113

Comment: Thanks! Yes, they are updated. I think the problem is that grub tries to mess around the USB devices and then get stuck. With the fan laptop base does not happen as it is a "dummy" device and it just uses USB for energy power.